# binary search program compiles but doesn't work

Tags: java

```
// program: BinSearch1.java
//
import java.util.*;

class BinSearch1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int size = 50;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        // declaring arrays
        int[]  item = new int[size];    // The list of numbers
        int    items=0;     // number of values in list
        int location;
        int seekValue;

        // method returns number of items entered by user.
        // user enters –1 to end entry process.
        //
        items = createInOrder( item );

        System.out.println("Element\t\tValue");

        // Display the current list
        //
        for( int i=0; i < items; i++ )
            System.out.println( i + "\t\t" + item[i] );

        System.out.print("Enter a value to seek: ");
        seekValue = console.nextInt();

        location = binSearch( item, items, seekValue);

        if( location >= 0 )
          System.out.println("Element found at location " + location);
        else
          System.out.println("Element not found in list");
    }

    // method: createInOrder
    //   This method will fill in a previously created array with values
    // in increasing order. When complete the method will return the number
    // of values inserted into the list.
    //
    public static int createInOrder( int[] n )
    {
        int    i;
        int    value=0;
        int    items=0;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        while( items < n.length && value >= 0 )
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive number to insert (negative to quit): ");
            value = console.nextInt();
            if( value >= 0 )
            {
                // insert into array

                // step 1- locate the proper space for the item.
                i=0;
                while( i < items && n[i] < value)
                    i++;

                // step 2- shift others down
                for( int j=items-1; j >=i; j--)
                    n[j+1] = n[j];

                // step 3- insert new item
                n[i] = value;
                items++;

            }
        }

        console.close();
        // return number of values entered
        return items;   
    }

   // INSERT MISSING CODE HERE! Write method binSearch
   /*
   public static void binSearch(int[] x, int y, int j)
   {
       int v, a;
       int[] p;
       for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
       {
           if(v < x[i])
           {
               x[i]=a;
               return a;
           }
           if(v> x[i])
           {
               x[i]/2=p[i];
               p[i]=a;
               return a;
           }

       }
   }
   public static void binSearch(int[] x, int y, int j)
   {
       int i;
       for(i=0; i<y.length; i++)
       {
           if( y.length/2 == x[i])
           {
               if(
            }
       }
    }
    */

    public static int binSearch (int[] arrayName, int items, int seekItem ) 
{

  int bottom = 0;
  int top = arrayName.length - 1;
  int middle;
  boolean found = false;
  int location = -1;

  while (bottom <= top && !found) {

    middle = (bottom + top) / 2;

    if(arrayName[middle] == seekItem) {            
      found = true;
      location = middle;
    } else if (arrayName[middle] < seekItem) {  
      bottom = middle + 1;
    } else {
      top = middle - 1;
    }
  }
  return location;
}


}
```

I'm writing this binary search program my teacher assigned. It compiles and I can put numbers, but when I try to seek the value and get the right index, it tells me the element is not in the list every time. What is wrong?

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are you still asking the same question?

Comment: yes, i tried fixing it. but i don't know where's the problem

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or is it just not working?

Comment: im not getting an error message, it just doesn't work, did i like write the code incorrectly or something?

Comment: when I run yur code i get: 
    Enter a value to seek: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)

Comment: Post the test data you are using and the output it gives. Try the recommendations given by Oil Charlesworth above. These things will help others help you, and will also show effort on your part above just "it's not working."

Comment: @Guido Yeah, I'm getting the same thing.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything with `Scanner`, but that error seems to be from the `console.close()` at the end of `createInOrder()`.

Comment: yes, remove the console.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the initialisation of "top":

```
public static int binSearch (int[] arrayName, int items, int seekItem ) 
{

int bottom = 0;
int top = arrayName.length - 1;  // is always 49
```

Try this:

```
public static int binSearch (int[] arrayName, int items, int seekItem ) 
{
int bottom = 0;
int top = items - 1;
```

Comment: Yep. Because `arrayName.length` is 50. Good catch.

Comment: if this solves your issue, please click on the "Accept" button on the left side. thx.